# Running docker-compose commands on the Docker host from Jenkins

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

So I have this setup where I have a server running Docker Engine(controlled by docker-compose) with my Jenkins and application containers(Node.js, React.js). The goal is to have a scm webhook start a Jenkins job that pulls the latest code, run tests and deploy the application services.

For the moment I only have one git repo, that contains the code of of both Node.js and React.js services, I have plans to move them into separate repos. What I want is basically that when someone pushes code to the master branch of that repo, I want the server to pull the git repo, run the tests, and deploy the application.

So for starters, how do I best get new code into the application containers? Should git pull be included in the Dockerfile for those images? And then I can maybe just rebuild those images to trigger the pull of new code? Or should Jenkins trigger a git pull in the server, and then inject those files to the containers/images?

Second part is, should I run tests in the same container that I will soon use to deploy the application?

At the moment I've bound the docker.sock like you can see in below to be able to communicate with Docker in the host. But how do I get ahold of docker-compose from Jenkins?

```
services:
  jenkins:      
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
      - "9000:8080"
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Comment: on commit or Merge request, you should do git pull on that commit, compile build and test. On successful merge of the commit, build and create image and push it to docker hub or deploy it on server

Comment: @SunilKumar thanks, so two different jobs then one for integration and one for deployment. The integration job could run up a build-agent Docker container, and run the build and tests in there. But for the deployment part, how do i get Jenkins to run docker-compose commands on the host that is running Jenkins itself.

Comment: now that you are able to integrate and run tests. you should have generated the jar/war file. you need to create/build a container and copy that file into container and add CMD or entrypoint on how that should be executed. You can do it with dockerfile or docker-compose.yml